# Routing traffic on specific interface over OpenVPN with FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, routing, openvpn

I'd like to setup OpenVPN between a FreeBSD client and an (Arch) Linux server such that

- All Internet-bound traffic explicitly sent from FreeBSD over the tunnel device is routed through OpenVPN

*but*

- The default gateway/route on the FreeBSD side remains untouched.

In other words, if I do something like `curl --interface tun0 example.com` on FreeBSD, I want the request to *example.com* to be routed through OpenVPN, but if I just do `curl example.com` I want that to ignore the VPN tunnel.

Thus far, I've successfully established a basic connection between the two machines, and both sides can see each other.

I can go through the tunnel to fetch data from the Web server running on the remote machine:

```
$ curl 10.8.0.1
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

For completeness, I also tested what happens if I explicitly specify the interface, and it works:

```
$ curl --interface 10.8.0.14 10.8.0.1
<!DOCTYPE html>
...

$ curl --interface tun0 10.8.0.1
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

However, using the interface for any other host/IP fails:

```
$ curl --interface tun0 example.com
*hang*

$ curl --interface tun0 93.184.216.34  # (the IP I got for example.com)
*hang*
```

OpenVPN (on the FreeBSD side) doesn't print any `RwRw` when I do this, so I assume (and I think correctly) that FreeBSD's network stack is insufficiently configured to know how to route arbitrary traffic on `tun0` through OpenVPN properly.

All the examples I've found to configure this kind of routing are Linux-specific; what do I do for FreeBSD?

I can make arbitrary changes on both the FreeBSD and Linux sides, if that makes configuration easier.

<sub><sup>I initially intended to post this to *networkengineering.stackexchange.com*, but the *freebsd* and *openvpn* tags aren't defined there so I'm posting here instead.</sup></sub>

Answer (score -2):

See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/838561/365849).

For a more detailed explanation on multiple gateways see [here](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).

The gist is to use a new routing table.

This is what I used - server being `10.8.0.1/24` and client `10.8.0.2/24`:

```
echo "10 vpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 table vpn
ip rule add from 10.8.0.2/24 table vpn
ip rule add to 10.8.8.1/24 table vpn
ip route flush cache
```

The first line should stick across reboots, but the rules will not.

**Edit:**
A much better way to run the commands when openvpn connects is to use the `up` directive in the openvpn config file:

```
up /etc/openvpn/tun0_up.sh
```

Comment: The question is specifically about FreeBSD (which has no `ip` command)